# Why don't interrogative sentences _start_ with a question mark?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Not all questions start with Wh- words, so why don't we start a question with a question mark to make it more obvious that it *is* actually a question?

For instance, when I'm reading a book which has a long interrogative sentence at the bottom of the right-hand page, it often isn't until I turn to the next page that I realize it is a question.

Not that this represents too much of a problem, but from a beginner's perspective it must make it harder to interpret the words of the sentence in the correct context.

Similarly, why don't we start exclamatory sentences with an exclamation mark?

I know this is a trivial question, but I'm wondering whether some kind of historical or colonial/imperial decision might explain the absence of these marks in the situations I describe.

P.S. *I am a student programmer, so pardon my ignorance / funniness*

Comment: ¿Did you know that in some languages, they do? ¡It’s really true!

Comment: It might not be as useful in English because a large fraction of questions begin with a wh- word.

Comment: This seems like a peeve, not a real question about punctuation. Many languages have no beginning punctuation; many languages do. English doesn't. It's certainly not by Imperial decree, so it must be historic. For the history, you might turn to the study of medieval manuscripts.

Comment: @Erik Kowal, since some of the venerable commentators on this site tell us that 'usage rules', you could try to start a trend.  One problem might be that if you want to use inverted question-marks [as in tchrist's response], many English-language keyboard-users wouldn't be able to cope.

Comment: @DavidGarner the original poster is the guy in the shaded box.

Comment: This question openly invites nothing but speculation. Why *do* you want interrogative sentences to start with a question mark? And how should we go about explaining the *absence* of something without essentially saying "there is no why"? That's just how it is because that's what generations before us gave us and we have nothing else. We need *some* kind of convention for indicating questions, and the convention we have *is* a convention, and so we're good. If every question did start with a question mark, you'd instead be asking "Why don't interrogative sentences start with an Ы?"

Comment: @RegDwigнt, Medica, There are a number of factual practical reasons. Languages that use question marks at both ends have features in common. So do languages that don't. There are also historical reasons too that are well known. The potential answers to this question might be multi-factorial, but they will not just be opinions. In fact the idea that this question is opinion base *is opinion based* and not based on any proper consideration of the question! The question highlights some useful and interesting facts about English.

Comment: For me, mostly because I haven't figured out that it's a question until I get to the end.

Comment: Thanks, @Mari-Lou A. Still haven't quite got to grips with this site , especially when using an iPhone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cases where a question sentence in English does not begin with an auxiliary verb (e.g. *do*, *be*); a modal (e.g. *can*, *might*, *will*, *would*) or a wh- word (e.g. *what*, *when*, *why*) are relatively few and far between.

Often the first word is a good indicator as to whether the sentence is going to be interrogative, unlike Italian where questions *can* look exactly the same as affirmative sentences. In Italian it is only the [*eroteme*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_mark) that *marks* or *signals* to the reader the phrase is a question.

> Sei stanco -->**You** are tired
>   Sei stanco? --> **Are** you tired? (note the [Subject–auxiliary inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93auxiliary_inversion#Uses_of_subject.E2.80.93auxiliary_inversion) )

[Question words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrogative_word) also exist  but in Italian there is only one word for *why* and *because*

> *Perché* sei stanco? --> **Why** are you tired?
>   *Perché* è tardi! --> **Because** it's late!

However, I never hear of any Italian speaker or learner asking why there aren't two question/exclamation signs to mark a sentence.

On the history of the question mark/ereteme Wikipedia tells us:

> Lynne Truss attributes an early form of the modern question mark in western language to Alcuin of York. Truss describes the *punctus interrogativus* of the **late 8th century** as "a lightning flash, striking from right to left"
>   [...]
>   According to a 2011 discovery by a Cambridge manuscript expert, Syriac
>   was the first language to use a punctuation mark to indicate an
>   interrogative sentence. The Syriac question mark has the form of a
>   vertical double dot

There's no mention of the English language ever having two question or exclamation marks in its history.

Comment: TIL – that unlike Spanish and Portuguese, Italian does not distinguish the interrogative and conjunctive _perché_’s. Interesting.

Comment: @MariLouA great insights & research, admirable :)

Comment: @user4453945 my pleasure, I'm glad my small effort helped you :)

Comment: Thank goodness you got in an answer before this good question was closed. (PS one of you +1's was from me)

Comment: @Araucaria thank you! Why not write a post on meta asking for it to be reopened? I answered because I saw the post received three upvotes, and so I thought it really must be a question that people have asked themselves.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Well, I've voted to reopen it. Some more reopen votes would do the trick. I'm kind of tired of doing reopen threads ... :(

Comment: @Araucaria  second one from me. I understand how you feel about meta... However, doesn't it need to be edited in order for it to enter the review queue (not sure about this)?

Comment: In older manuscripts, a point was used at the end of sentences; if it was a question, the point was elevated more from the baseline than a period. I think we have a lot to thank Alcuin of York for.